# Make carousel button labels auto slide with carousel slides

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel, autoscroll

[image]

I have the following carousel set up. It auto slides with the data-ride bootstrap functionality. I would like the button labels to change when the slides scrolls. Does anyone know how to implement this functionality?

Comment: I don't want to use the carousel-indicators class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by binding a function to the slide bootstrap function.

Here is where I bound my slide labels function to the carousel bootstrap slide function.

```
            var r = new ComponentCarouselLayout();
            var carousel = $('#carousel-tour');
            carousel.bind('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
                r.slideLabels(carousel);
            });
```

Here is my slide labels function which updates which label is active.

```
slideLabels: function(carousel) {
    var labelItems = $(carousel).closest('.btn-group-carousel').find('#ts-btn-toggles label');
    var labelItem;
    for (var i = 0; i < labelItems.length; i++) {
        labelItem = labelItems[i];
        if ($(labelItem).hasClass("active")) {
            $(labelItem).removeClass("active");
            var start = labelItem;
            var nextLabelItem = labelItems[($.inArray(start, labelItems) + 1) % labelItems.length];
            $(nextLabelItem).addClass("active");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```